# Как вызвать функцию MS SQL асинхронно в linq to EF?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Создал функцию в MS SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SearchUserFTS(@SearchWord NVARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
(
   SELECT *
   FROM Users
   WHERE CONTAINS(*,@SearchWord)
)
GO
```

Импортировал её в модель и пытаюсь вызвать:

```
public async Task<User[]> SearchUserFTS(String search_word)
{
    using (REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities db = new REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities())
    {
        IQueryable<User> users = db.SearchUserFTS(search_word);
    }
}
```

Но к сожалению она полностью синхронная... Вопрос в том как её вызвать асинхронно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам дошёл до ответа, вот такое решение у меня:

```
public async Task<User[]> SearchUserFTS(String search_word)
{
    using (REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities db = new REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities())
    {
        IQueryable<User> search_user_fts = db.SearchUserFTS(search_word);
        return await search_user_fts.ToArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем вам в этом коде `async` и `await`? вы можете убрать их и получите тот же результат. Вызывайте `await` только там, где уже будут использоваться эти данные

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен